# Calculate the area between $x^2 = py$,$ x^2 = qy$, and $y = ax$, $y = bx$!

Tags: calculus

So how do you calculate the area between $x^2 = py$,$ x^2 = qy$, and $y = ax$, $y = bx$?

I have a solution, it might be bad, so that is why I'm asking.

So I drew the area, supposing that $b>a$ and $p>q$.

The points of intersections in the area we are looking for are: $ap$, $bp$, $aq$,$bq$.

Let $I$ be the area. So I suppose that

$$I=\int_{ap}^{bp}\int_{bx}^{\frac{1}{p}x^2}\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{bp}^{aq}\int_{ax}^{bx}\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{aq}^{bq}\int_{\frac{1}{q}x}^{bx}\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Is this right?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Actually two different possibilities, depends which is bigger, $ap$ or $bq$

Comment: Does my answer cover one of the possibilities?

Comment: no. In either case, one of the integrals, the $x$ endpoints, goes either from $bq$ to $ap$ if that is increasing order, otherwise $ap$ to $bq.$ Please draw two graphs, one with $a=2, p=5, b=q=3,$ the other graph with $a=2, p=4, b=q=3.$

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that $ b > a > 0 $ and  $ p > q > 0 $. Solve all with respect to $ y $ and you get : $ y=ax, y=bx, y=(1/q)x^2, y=(1/p)x^2 $. By drawing up these functions with the way we defined the constants, the calculation of the area will go like that :

1) Find the intersections :

$ ax=(1/q)x^2 \Leftrightarrow x=aq $ (calculating the others) : $x=aq, x=ap, x=bp, x= bq $

2) Looking carefully on the plot and making sub-areas, the total area is :

$\int_{aq}^{bq}((1/q)x^2 - ax) dx + \int_{bq}^{bp} (bx - (1/p)x^2)  dx - \int_{bq}^{ap} (ax - (1/p)x^2)  dx $

3) The  condition is that $ ap > bq $ . Otherwise, the solution changes but is in the same way of thinking.

The exercise is demanding because you need to see and subtract a small area between $ax $ and $ (1/p)x^2 $. It took some time to make a good plot and notice the small things. I hope I haven't done any silly mistake with the limits of integration. Feel free to ask me anything that you may want to ask or point out something that doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Thanks! Now I feel like, I understand this, but I need be more careful with this.